# Compute Engine in WordPress is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, google-compute-engine

I have installed a WordPress site on Google Cloud (Compute Engine instance) trough Click-to-Deploy. An internal and external IP addresses were assigned. I overwrote this site with another, a WordPress than I had on another server. I modified database entries like **siteurl** and **home** on wp-options table with the external IP assigned, and did the same on WordPress back-end Settings page.

The first (static, non-blog) page displayed, but the other pages threw an 404 error. I have created a new page, followed the link displayed when created, but a 404 appeared again. 
Then I tried to modify the two entries on the database(siteurl and home on wp-options table) with the internal IP. The front page didn't load anymore. I reverted this changes and resaved Settings on back-end, but the front page still doesn't load. It shows

> "The server at -internal IP- is taking too long to respond".

Phpmyadmin and backend (which addresses contain the external IP) work.

The billing is turned on for the project.

How to make the front page load again? Where is the error, in general? Isn't it possible to run a WordPress site without a DNS?

**EDIT:** I cleared the cache and the front page displays again. The last 2 questions remain, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer was that I had to press the Save button on the back-end Permalinks Page